# como faço para verificar novamente credenciais após usuário logar e ficar salvo no firebase

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, firebase

Estou com um aplicativo que exige login com e-mail e senha. As credenciais eu gero manualmente dentro do firebase e passo para o usuário conseguir logar no aplicativo e depois de uma vez logado o usuário não precisa mais ficar logando. Porém acontece que mesmo após eu excluir as credenciais do usuário no firebase ele continua conseguindo logar já que vai de forma automática. Como faço para que continue dessa forma do usuário logar uma vez e não precisar mais porém quero que quando eu excluir as credenciais dele ele não consiga mais logar e fique na tela pedindo login.

public void validarautenticacao(View v) {
String login = usuario1.getText().toString();
String pass = senha1.getText().toString();

```
    if (!login.isEmpty()) {
        if (!pass.isEmpty()) {
            usuario usuario = new usuario();
            usuario.setUsuario(login);
            usuario.setSenha(pass);

            logar(usuario);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha a Senha ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Preencha o Usuário", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void logar(usuario usuario) {

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getUsuario(), usuario.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                abrirhome();
            } else {
                String excessao = "";
                try {
                    throw task.getException();
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                    excessao = "Usuário não cadastrado";
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    excessao = "E-mail ou senha incorretos";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    excessao = "Erro ao logar" + e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(teladelogin.this, excessao, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}

private void abrirhome() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(teladelogin.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser usuarioatual = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (usuarioatual != null) {
        abrirhome();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O cliente depois que loga uma vez permanece logado mesmo após que eu excluo a conta dele na base de dados.